# Efficiently retrieving all unique records for a facet value along with record counts in Algolia

Tags: algolia

I'm using Algolia to power search in my app. I have an index called `prod_COACHES` in which I have some records with an object key called `speciality1`.

The data structure for `speciality1` looks like this:

[image]

I have enabled `speciality1.itemName` as an Algolia 'facet' so that I can filter on it. All good so far and working nicely. Now, in my Algolia dashboard I can see a nice bit of UI that shows me every unique facet (in this case my specialisations) along with the number of records for each facet:

[image]

As it happens, I want to show exactly this information on my own UI in my app but I'm not sure how to get this data from Algolia in the most efficient way. I'm using the client side AlgoliaSearch Javascript SDK. How do I run a search to retrieve every unique `speciality1.itemName` and the number of records for each unique `speciality1.itemName` so I can build my own UI just like the above?

I have gone through the docs and followed the examples but my question is really about finding the most efficient way to do this from someone who really knows Algolia well, rather than hack my own solution together. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've enabled `attributesForFaceting` on the attribute `speciality1.itemName`. You can retrieve the facet values for the given attribue with the search parameter [`facets`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/facets/). The Algolia response will now contain a map with `value:count`. Here is an example with the JavaScript client:

```
import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch';

const client = algoliasearch('XXX', 'XXX');
const index = client.initIndex('XXX');

index.search('', {
  facets: ['speciality1.itemName']
}).then(result => {
  console.log(result.facets)
});
```

If you want to easily build a search UI, you should take a look at the [InstantSearch](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/what-is-instantsearch/js/) libraries. It's built on top of Algolia to ease the state/ui management for such UI. Many flavours are available e.g. Vanilla, React.